# How do I parse out all US states from comma separated strings in Python from an excel file.

Tags: python, excel, combinations

I have a file that has a column with names, and another with comma separated US licenses, for example, AZ,CA,CO,DC,HI,IA,ID; but any combination of 50 states is possible. I have another file that has a certain value attached to each state, for example AZ=4, CA=30, DC=23, and so on for all 50.

I need to add up the amount that each person is holding via their combination of licenses. Say, someone with just CA, would have 30, while some one with AZ, CA and DC, would end up with 30+4+23=57; and any combination of 50 licenses is possible.

I know a bit of Python, but not enough to know how to even get started, what packages to use, what the architecture should be..

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am told to use Pandas to get at each of the individual states in your excel file. 
I then use a dictionary structure to store state values and look up sates from the above to these.